# Force python module to be installed in certain directory

Tags: python, module, installation

Is there any way to force python module to be installed in the following directory? `/usr/lib/python2.7`

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a non-answer, but are you able to use virtualenv?

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

It makes dealing with multiple versions of Python and library management amazingly easy. And it's simple to use once you get used to it.

You can create a Python 2.7 virtualenv and pip/easy_install will automatically install modules to it.

Comment: thanks, but, let me change the question: how to make sure that a module (e.g. https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language) that is supposed to be installed already, is properly installed? This is a very general question, I know, but the thing is, that I am really struggling make it work...

Comment: The easiest way I know is to run the python shell (usually just "python" at a command prompt) and try importing the module with "import guess_language". If you get an ImportError, it's not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Install the module:

> sudo pip-2.7 install guess_language

Validate import and functionality:

`> Python2.7`
`>>> import guess_language`
`>>> print guess_language.guessLanguage(u"שלום לכם")`

> he

Comment: @first question: I don't have pip-2.7. I have only pip. Is that a problem?

Comment: When you install pip, it installs specific "pips" per a python interpreter. You might have both 2.7 and 2.6 installed on your machine. When you invoke "python" on the command line, which interpreter starts? 2.7? 2.6?